# Meta key in wp_query bug?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, bug

```
$query_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'order'=> 'desc',
'orderby' => 'meta_value date',
'paged' => $paged
 );
```

This is my current query to sort posts. What it does that it shows posts with any post meta first and then sorts the remaining ones by date. However in the [wordpress reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) it says that `meta_key` should be present for it to work.

What's actually going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You must add meta_key to your array. How else the query will know what meta value to use?

Try adding `'meta_key' => 'your_key'`

Comment: but without putting meta_key it shows the posts with custom fields first and then shows the remaining ones.. my question is why does that happen

Comment: What do you want to happen? it is normal - it is ordering posts with some `"meta_value"` first, and then the ones without it at. normal `SELECT` query action.

Comment: so what is that meta value? @kirillrocks